# Is it true that $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{m}}{x^n+1}dx=\frac{\pi}{n\sin{(\frac{m+1}{n}\pi})}$?

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

Is it true that $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{m}}{x^n+1}dx=\frac{\pi}{n\sin{(\frac{m+1}{n}\pi})}$$
where $1\leq m<n$ ?

If so, how can I prove it?

Comment: Certainly not true when $m=n-1.$

Comment: Oops, then, how is it if $0<m<n-1$?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function

Comment: Set $x^n=y$ then use beta function

Comment: Alternatively, check out [Ramanujan's master theorem's alternative formulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan%27s_master_theorem) and consider $\frac{1}{x+1}$'s series expansion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x=\tan^{2/n} t \implies dx= \frac{2}{n} \tan^{2/n-1}t \sec^2 t dt$, then
$$I=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^m}{1+x^n} dx= \frac{2}{n} \int _{0}^{\pi/2}\sin ^{2m/n+2/n-1} t ~ \cos^{1-2m/n-2/n}~ t dt =\frac{1}{n}\Gamma((m+1)/n)\Gamma(1-(m+1)/n)$$ 
By using $\Gamma(z) \Gamma(1-z)=\pi \csc z,$ we get $$ I=\frac{\pi}{n \sin (\frac{(m+1)\pi}{n})}$$

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Lord Shark the Unknown, @Ali Shather, and @Dr Zafar Ahmed DSc, I was able to prove it.

Let $x^n=y$, then $dx=\frac{y^{1/n-1}}{n}dy$ ,
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{m}}{x^n+1}dx 
=\frac{1}{n}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{y^{m/n+1/n-1}}{y+1}dy 
=\frac{1}{n}\mathrm{B}(m/n+1/n,1-(m/n+1/n)) 
=\frac{\pi}{n\sin{\pi(m/n+1/n)}}$$
For $0<m/n+1/n<1\implies-1<m<n-1$